# Python3. ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, elementtree

**Code:**

```
  import urllib.request 
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  x = input('Enter a URL:') 
  stuff = ET.fromstring(x)
```

**Error:**

line 1320, in XML
parser.feed(text)
File "string", line None
xml.etree.**ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5**

*Does anyone know how to fix the code and where's the problem?*

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace? What are you providing as input?

Comment: I changed the code like this and everything is working now:          `import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
x = input('Enter a URL:')
stuff = urllib.request.urlopen(x)
y = stuff.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(y)`